# History back() Method go back twice

Tags: javascript, html, button

Using this sample code as an example:
    Go Back

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Then, pressing this button will be the same as pressing the back button once on the browser.

However I would like to have a button that makes the back button pressed twice. 
I tried `window.history.back(-2);` but it doesnt work.
also tried `window.history.go(-2);` but it doesnt give desired results. 
I could have the button link back to the page but the reason why i want it to go back instead is so that previously entered data in a form is preserved.

Comment: Actually window.history.go(-2); should work, can you publish a snippet?

Comment: Wow, it is working as expected now. I swear it wasn't working as expected a few moments ago. thank you though.

Answer (score 7):

Now

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

works; strange.